# How to make auto touch with given x and y co-ordinate using ios

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have problem to solve. There are two `UIImageView`.

1. Image
2. Selected icon displays tick icon whether it is selected or not.

Problem occurs when a user touches the tick icon, the image dosen't get selected. I am planning to get x and y coordinates from where i touched then auto touch on images automatically. Is it possible?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is the tick icon? Is it a subview of the imageView? Does point 2 mean the tick icon is always there, or that it appears when the image view has been selected?

Comment: Yes, Sorry for question, i am a webdeveloper learning ios.